# Can dotnet pack create a nuget package without adding content files from other nuget packages?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, pack

I'm trying to setup a library nuget package for .net core with the `dotnet pack` command, however, instead of just having a dll included in the nuget package, a content file from another references nuget is added (which makes the nuget file size 9.6MB instead of 59KB).

Is there a way to avoid getting files and content from other nuget packages in a nuget library project?

to reproduce:
Create a .net core library 
Add Hl7.Fhir.Specification.STU3 nuget reference
run dotnet pack

The nuspec file in the newly created nuget package, will reveal that the specification.zip file is regarded as content that must be added.

I've tried testing with a custom nuspec file which is basicly a copy from the dotnet output, but without the content reference. The problem I see, is that the nuspec file contains a lot of references which must be maintained somehow.

Comment: Could excluding assets of the referenced package do the Job? I'm not sure if it applies to .zip-files also, have only seen excluding .cs-files.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#controlling-dependency-assets

Comment: I just tested it and I couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Peter Wurzinger's suggestion worked for me. It's a shame he posted as a comment, rather than an answer, since he deserves the rep points. Anyway, this is my csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Hl7.Fhir.Specification.STU3" Version="0.96.0" ExcludeAssets="contentFiles" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

when I pack, the `bin\Debug\test.1.0.0.nuspec` file does not contain the specification.zip file elements that exists when I don't use `ExcludeAssets`.

Comment: Ah alright, so it seems that arbitrary files can indeed be excluded using ExcludeAssets - good to know!

Comment: well, it excludes all contentFiles from the package. If you had a package with multiple contentFiles and you want to keep some and exclude others, it would be more difficult.

Comment: I didin't set ExcludeAssets="contentFiles", but to "all", so that's where my mistake was.

Comment: The package size went from 9.5MB to 28KB, so the setting really matters in the cases where you get content files included from a referenced package

Comment: Maybe NuGet ignores `ExcludeAssets="all"`, because semantically that's the same as not referencing the package at all, so it's unlikely to ever be what the user wants (you can comment out the line if you want to remove it temporarily without removing it from the file).